# How to mimick D3JS scaleTime display on scaleLinear to account for discontinuous time series (financial data)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

D3JS' scaleTime creates a continuous scale based on the provided domain. When providing intraday data, the dataset is often discontinuous, for example on a 1 minute chart, there can be no trades for many 1 minute periods.

To account for this I've switched to scaleLinear, but now the formatting is not the same. And the zoom functionality is also not the same.

I've looked into d3fc but it looks outdated, and doesn't fit my requirements.

Here is my code for generating the xAxis:

```
    const xScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([visibleBars.length - 1, 0])
        .range([0, xAxisWidth]);

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat((d, i) => {
        const index = Math.round(d as any);
        if (index >= 0 && index < visibleBars.length) {
            const timestamp = new Date(visibleBars[index].t);
            if (chartSpan === 'day') {
                return d3.timeFormat("%b '%y")(timestamp);
            } else {
                return d3.timeFormat('%H:%M')(timestamp);
            }
        }
        return '';
    });

    xAxisSVG
        .append('g')
        .call(xAxis);
```

This successfully generates an x axis for my chart, but the display of the axis is incorrect.
In scaleTime, the values round as described here: https://d3js.org/d3-scale/time

On the daily chart, the values don't round to the first day of the month: [image]

And on the intraday chart, the time values also don't round nicely: [image]

For reference, here is what the scaleTime looks like on a daily chart: [image]

And on the intraday chart:
[image]

I'm trying to achieve the same display, rounding, and zoom functionality as scaleTime using scaleLinear in order to account for discontinuous data.